# Idiomatically group String (count consecutively repeated characters)

Tags: kotlin, idioms

How with what idioms do I achieve the desired effect?

```
val input = "aaaabbbcca"

val result = input.(here do the transformations)

val output = listOf("a" to 4, "b" to 3, "c" to 2, "a" to 1)

assert(result == output)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fun way to do it immutably using [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html)

```
fun main() {
    val result = "aaaabbbcca"
        .chunked(1)
        .fold(emptyList<Pair<String, Int>>()) { list, current ->
            val (prev, count) = list.lastOrNull() ?: Pair(current, 0)
            if (prev == current) list.dropLast(1) + Pair(current, count + 1)
            else list + Pair(current, 1)
        }

    val output = listOf("a" to 4, "b" to 3, "c" to 2, "a" to 1)
    check(result == output)
    println(result)
}
```

Output:

```
[(a, 4), (b, 3), (c, 2), (a, 1)]
```

Comment: Note that if you're ok with `Pair<Char, Int>`, you can replace `String` with `Char` and remove the `.chunked(1)` call.

Comment: I dread to think just how many temporary objects that creates… :-)  You could probably improve it by making the list mutable, and replacing Pair with a mutable data class.  But it's interesting how what looks like such a simple problem doesn't seem to have any simple solutions!

Comment: I agree; Kotlin has these immutable types and functions, but looking at the JVM implementations they create objects all over the place. I'm wondering if there is any clever GC, or if it's better optimized for the non-jvm compilers. Comparing to something like Erlang that optimises for immutable operations, I always hesitate when doing immutable list operations in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky little problem, and I can't find a particular idiomatic solution.

However, here's one that's quite concise:

```
val result = input.replace(Regex("(.)(?!\\1)(.)"), "$1§$2")
                  .split("§")
                  .map{ Pair(it[0], it.length) }
```

It uses a complicated little regex to insert a marker character (`§` here, though of course it would work with any character that can't be in the input) between every pair of different characters.   (`(?…)` is a zero-width look-ahead assertion, so `(?!\1)` asserts that the next character is different from the previous one.  We need to include the next character in the match, otherwise it'll append a marker after the last character too.)

That gives `aaaa§bbb§cc§a` in this case.

We then split the string at the marker, giving a list of character groups (in this case `"aaaa", "bbb", "cc", "a"`), which it's easy to convert into (character,length) pairs.

Using a regex is not always a good solution, especially when it's complicated and unintuitive like this one.  So this might not be a good choice in production code.  On the other hand, a solution using `fold()` or `reduce()` probably wouldn't be that much easier to read, either.  In fact, the most maintainable solution might be the old-fashioned one of looping over the characters…

Comment: PS. I realise that this gives characters, not strings.  That's arguably a better choice — but if you want strings, to exactly match the question, then replace the `it[0]` with `it.substring(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are no good (efficient, readable) idiomatic ways to solve this. We can use a good, old and boring loop approach. To make it at least a little more funny, we can do it with a lazy computing, utilizing coroutines:

```
fun String.countConsecutive() = sequence {
    if (isEmpty()) return@sequence
    val it = iterator()
    var curr = it.next()
    var count = 1
    it.forEach {
        if (curr == it) {
            count++
        } else {
            yield(curr.toString() to count)
            curr = it
            count = 1
        }
    }
    yield(curr.toString() to count)
}
```

This is good if our string is very long and we only need to iterate over consecutive groups. Even better if we don't need to iterate over all of them.