# Kotlin group following items with a same type preserving an order

Tags: list, algorithm, kotlin, grouping

I'd like to group items on a list with a same type preserving and order. But only if they following each other.
Is there any smarter way than simple for?

Input:

```
A A B A A A A C C A
```

Output:

```
A A
B
A A A A
C C 
A
```

Comment: Is that covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802712/idiomatically-group-string-count-consecutively-repeated-characters)?  Also may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248942/how-to-split-a-list-into-sublists-using-a-predicate-with-kotlin), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val list = listOf("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A")

val result = list.foldIndexed(mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()) { index, acc, value ->
  when {
    index > 0 && list[index - 1] == value -> acc.last().add(value)
    else                                  -> acc.add(mutableListOf(value))
  }
  acc
}

result.forEach(::println)
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/RVSPbk13z)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a Sequence

```
fun collectSame(src: List<String>): Sequence<Pair<String, List<String>>> = sequence {
    var currentGroupKey: String? = null
    val collector = mutableListOf<String>()
    src.forEach {
        if(currentGroupKey==null || currentGroupKey != it) {
            currentGroupKey = it
            if(collector.isNotEmpty()) {
                yield(currentGroupKey!! to collector)
                collector.clear()
            }
        }
        collector.add(it)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val answer = collectSame(listOf("A","A","B","A","A","A","A","C","C","A"))
    answer.forEach {
        println(it.second)
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
[A, A]
[B]
[A, A, A, A]
[C, C]
```

There may some way to do this better than my solution with `grouping`.